# Polymer-ready fires on IE11 but not on Firefox or Chrome

Tags: javascript, import, polymer

I've come across an unexpected problem.

I have two pages with polymer. Both work just fine on IE11, no problems at all (except for the slow performance).
Now, on Firefox and Chrome, one of them is not working, never fires polymer-ready, the other one works just fine.
If anything, one would think that IE would be the one with troubles.

Related to this non-firing behavior, the only polymer elements this page shows on FF or Chrome are the main toolbars, and the stuff inside of them, nothing more.
I just don't know what to try next.

Here are the headers. The first one is from the page which works everywhere, no problems.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes" />
    <title>N-Adviser</title>
    [... a bunch of element imports ...]
    <script src="components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
    <style shim-shadowdom>
        [...some styling...]
    </style>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

And here's the bad one

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="headPortal" runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes" />
    <title>Portal</title>
    <link rel="import" href="components/font-roboto/roboto.html" />
    <link rel="import" href="components/polymer/polymer.html" />
    [...a bunch of element imports...]
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/LoginStyle.css" shim-shadowdom />
    <script src="components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
    <style></style>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

Can't see any differences, apart from the fact that one of them imports its CSS from an external file, which shouldn't matter.

Both of them have their javascript code after all the html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert("docready");
    });
    window.addEventListener('polymer-ready', function (e) {
        alert("polready");
    [...]
</script>
```

Both fire `document.ready`, but only the first one fires polymer-ready. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

The webcomponents.js should be loaded before the html imports. Try to move that script tag above all imports (see also https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/start/creatingelements.html). That should be all.

I think I can explain the strange behavior. Maybe in the first example in the import files there are no Polymer specific functions and in the second there are (note that Polymer != web components. webcomponents.js contains Polymer-specific functionality). Because IE11 does not support web components natively, it skips the html import tags (it doesn't know them) and the Polymer's polyfill then scans the document after loading webcomponents.js and loads them up (because that's is a function in the polyfill).

Because Chrome and FF do have web component support they 'see' the html import before the webcomponents.js and the Polymer functions are not loaded yet. Therefore it doesn't work.

Comment: I thought I had tested with every order on the imports, but tried again changing webcomponents.js. Still not working, polymer-ready not firing :/
Also, I didn't say it on my question, but the page that is working is much more complex than the other one, and imports all the things the "bad" one does, plus many others. I'll remember your explanation because it can be useful, but not in this situation.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that your explanation makes perfect sense, still doesn't fix the problem